# JS Create two dates & sort them

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on an application that receives a response from the database that doesn't contain a direct timestamp, and every day when I check the app, the data is being received differently, causing my charts to render backwards unless I do a .reverse() (or take it out).

I would like to fix this permanently with a sort(), but I'm not sure how to call the function since the response doesn't contain direct timestamps. These are example response from the API:

```
"records": [
    { 
      "dateRep": "01/05/2020",
      "day": "1",
      "month": "5",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "222",
      "deaths": "4",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "30/04/2020",
      "day": "30",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "122",
      "deaths": "0",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "29/04/2020",
      "day": "29",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "124",
      "deaths": "3",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    },
```

My current code is thus, but it isn't working:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countriesList.length; i++) {
    dataWorldWideEuropa.sort(
        (a, b) => new Date(a.year,a.month,a.day) > new Date(b.year,b.month,b.day)
    ).map(datum => {
    // do work here
    });
}
```

Can I easily convert the .day, .month and .year fields from my response into a Date and then sort by that so I don't need to keep adding and removing .reverse() when the API changes?

Comment: why don't you pass date rep to the date constructor it will parse the date correctly.

Comment: For right now, the dataset is taking so long to run a sort command that I instead ran the first few entries of the array into a shorter one, created another variable called "direction" that returns 0 if the first entry is smaller than the first, 1 if the second entry is smaller. And then an if statement so that if the "direction" variable is bigger than 0, it runs the reverse() function. So far it's working, we'll see how it looks tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

You just need to use `.sort()` on your array of data and calculate the difference between a and b:

`return new Date(a.year, a.month, a.day) - new Date(b.year, b.month, b.day);`

As sort expects less than 1 or greater than to determine if one item is ahead/behind of another (or zero if they are equivalent).

```js
const sorted = getRecords().sort((a,b) => {
  return new Date(a.year, a.month, a.day) - new Date(b.year, b.month, b.day);
});

console.log(sorted)


function getRecords(){

  return [
    { 
      "dateRep": "01/05/2020",
      "day": "1",
      "month": "5",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "222",
      "deaths": "4",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "30/04/2020",
      "day": "30",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "122",
      "deaths": "0",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    }, 
    { 
      "dateRep": "29/04/2020",
      "day": "29",
      "month": "4",
      "year": "2020",
      "cases": "124",
      "deaths": "3",
      "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
      "geoId": "AF",
      "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
      "popData2018": "37172386",
      "continentExp": "Asia"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code works, but I wound up doing something slightly different. The array was just too big to loop through for sorting, so I just grabbed the first couple of dates, then used the results of comparing them (0 if the first is bigger, 1 if the second is bigger) and then used that value to determine whether or not to do a reverse() on the array. It seems to be working!